# Google keeps re-signing in despite sign out

Tags: javascript, php, google-api

I'm trying to implement the [Google Sign-In](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in) for websites but I'm struggling to keep a user signed out. I'm using a separate page to handle the sign out process (it also unsets various session details) before passing the user back to the login page. Problem is that when they hit that login page, Google views them as signed in and pushes them to the onSuccess step.

Here's the login page:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>

    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <meta name="google-signin-client_id" content="[clientIDstuffHere].apps.googleusercontent.com">

</head>
<body class="loginPage">

    <div id="loginBox">

        <?php if(isset($_GET['error'])) { ?>

            <p class="loginError"><?php echo $_GET['error'] ?></p>

        <?php } ?>

        <div id="googleSignIn"></div>

    </div>

    <script>

    function onSuccess(googleUser) {
        var id_token = googleUser.getAuthResponse().id_token;
        window.location.href = "auth.php?id_token=" + id_token;
    }

    function onFailure(error) {
        console.log(error);
    }

    function renderButton() {
        gapi.signin2.render('googleSignIn', {
            'scope': 'profile email',
            'width': 240,
            'height': 50,
            'longtitle': true,
            'theme': 'dark',
            'onsuccess': onSuccess,
            'onfailure': onFailure
        });
    } 

    </script>

    <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js?onload=renderButton" async defer></script>

</body>
</html>
```

And the logout page:

```
<?php

session_start();
session_unset();
session_destroy();

?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>

    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <meta name="google-signin-client_id" content="[clientIDstuffHere].apps.googleusercontent.com">

</head>
<body>
<script>

function loadAndExit() {
  gapi.load('auth2', function() {
    gapi.auth2.init().then(() => {
        var auth2 = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance();
        auth2.signOut();
        auth2.disconnect();
    });
  });
  window.location.href = "index.php";
}

</script>
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js?onload=loadAndExit" async defer></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: `window.location.href = "index.php";` should happen after your deepest Asynchronous call, which is inside your `.then` function, otherwise the page changes before the code executes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read my comment, then place `location = 'index.php';` directly after `auth2.disconnect();`

Comment: Yes, it's fine to use `location` just like that.